# Is there any difference between a predicate using a literal value or a parameter value when that value will always be the same?

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2016

I have a query that always filters on a status, is there a performance benefit of one of these ways over the other?

(This is in the context of an ad-hoc query. The datatype of UserStatus is int)

```
...
AND UserStatus = 1
...
```

or

```
DECLARE @userStatus int = 1
...
AND UserStatus = @userStatus
...
```

(p.s. please don't talk about how params and literals are different when the values are unknown/changing, that's a different topic)

Comment: Is this in the context or a stored procedure or ad-hoc T-SQL? Could you add your SQL Server version as a tag please?

Comment: @George.Palacios Thanks, I updated the question. I'd love to know more about why that would matter between ad-hoc and sproc.

Comment: Yes: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/06/tuning-stored-procedures-local-variables-problems/

Comment: @JeremyWeir it shouldn't matter wheather or not the values are changing. If you are using a local variable instead of a literal you're going to get a an estimate based on denisty * # of rows in a table instead of using the histogram in order to calculate your cardinality estimate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Alright assuming that you are talking about a local variable running from a query in SSMS since it hasn't been specified otherwise. Even if you use the same value for the 
`AND UserStatus = @userStatus` that you would use in the literal `AND UserStatus = 1` you will see a difference in your execution plan due to how the cardinality estimate is generated.

When you use a literal value SQL Server will go out to the [histogram](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-show-statistics-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#histogram) for that table and see where that value of fits within the range key. The estimate gathered on that will result in one of two scenarios.

**HISTOGRAM DIRECT HIT** Essentially this means there is a `RANGE_HI_KEY`(Upper column value for any step in the histogram) value for that specific literal value in your query and therefore the estimate will match the number of `EQ_ROWS`(# of rows whose value equals the `RANGE_HI_KEY`) in the histogram. This means your estimate will be the number of rows that match that value based on the last time you updated statistics.

**HISTOGRAM INTRA-STEP HIT** This is when the value exists in a range between two `RANGE_HI_KEY` values. When your literal value is between that range it is calculated by the `RANGE_ROWS`(number of rows between two histogram steps), `DINSTINCT_RANGE`(the number of distinct values within that histogram step), and `AVG_RANGE_ROWS` (`RANGE_ROWS`/`DISTINCT_RANGE_ROWS`) and that will give you your estimate.

However when you run with a local variable you will no longer go to the Histogram for these values since the `@Variable` isn't known at runtime.

For more information on this topic I recommend reading this white paper by [Joe Sack.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn673537.aspx)

**DENSITY VECTOR** When there is no specific value to go with then SQL server instead uses a Density to be able to determine the estimated number of rows returned for that predicate. Density being 1/ the number of distinct values within that column. So then your cardinality estimation will be Density * the number of rows in the table.

So long story short no. Even if you run the same value over and over with a local variable you will not get the same results for reasons further explained in the link Eric Provided from [Kendra Little](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/06/tuning-stored-procedures-local-variables-problems/).

Comment: I added a slight correction. Feel free to roll-back if it doesn't describe what you meant.

Comment: Looks good Man.

Answer (score 7):

A literal value is known to the optimizer (so it can estimate selectivity based on that value).

A parameter value (stored procedure, function) is sniffed at execution time. A subsequent execution might have some other value, for which the previously compiled plan might not be optimal.

For a variable, the value is not known to the optimizer. It might be able to look at density (on *average* we have this many rows for a certain value), or it uses hard-wired estimates (like for instance > result in 10% selectivity, or whatever those ward-wired percentages might be).

Comment: So if the value will never change, does a literal act differently than a param?

Comment: Since the param will be sniffed it will behave the same as the literal, assuming you always have the same value. But a variable is a totally different thing!

Comment: Got it, so there's a difference between local variable used as a parameterized value and a sproc parameter used as a parameterized value?

Comment: @JeremyWeir: Yes, there is, that's why Erik suggested reading [Brent Ozar's article](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/06/tuning-stored-procedures-local-variables-problems/) above.